# How to style enabled/disabled state of ProgressBar in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm using Java.

I have a custom view which contains a ProgressBar and a TextView that behave together like a Button. I want to have the ProgressBar behave like a Button's background, so right now I wanted to implement enabled/disabled behavior/styling.

[image]

Is there a xml way to do it? If not, is there a clean way to do it in code?

Comment: Please Edit your post with example What exactly you want to do and also what is your current view.

Comment: @VatsalDholakiya I have added a picture but I really don't think the specific xml is important. I have found a way which uses selector drawables in a multifile configuration but I'm still reading and experimenting if it's the right approach.

Comment: Yes, you are right you can do that with selector in Drawable.

Comment: If you want to show progressBar OR something else after clicking on button then you can use : 
BtnID.setVisibility(View.GONE); and ProgressBar_ID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: @VatsalDholakiya so you are saying it would be better to have a Button and a ProgressBar styled like a button simultaneously and use the styled enabled/disabled states of the Button instead of creating enabled/disabled versions of the ProgressBar?

Comment: Yes, I mean you should go with it if you want to show totally different view after clicking on button Instead of, Selector, Because when you use selector then you can only customize particular component like size, color, background etc.